# How to achieve this bevel button in CSS?

Tags: css, button, bevelled

Is it possible to create a button that look like this in CSS:

[image: bevel button]

Of course I don't mean using an image as background, I can easily do that. I'm talking about the webkit type of solution.

Comment: http://www.cssbuttongenerator.com/ can you give you an idea if you look at the code it generates

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The short answer is **yes, it can be done**. I went ahead and gave it a shot.

These are the steps I took:

- I opened your bitmap in Sketch, my favorite graphical tool for all things web
- I zoomed in to your bitmap, traced the outline with a rounded rectangle and gave it the correct color
- I started adding `box-shadow`s, both outside and inset, to replicate the bitmap as close as possible. Note that I only used black and white (with varying alpha values) for the box shadows. This way you can easily change the color of the button by just changing the `background-color`.
- I also added two extra shapes for the bottom shadow and the top glow, as I did not manage to get this right with just box shadows. As long as it are just 2 elements that should not be a problem however, you can use the `:before` and `:after` pseudo elements to include these in your css.

The resulting image looks something like this (not exact, but pretty close I think):
[image]

And then I translated the drawing to css, by choosing 'copy css attributes' and manually adding the :before and :after elements and doing some fine tuning. This is the (unprefixed) css I came up with:

```
.button {
    display: inline-block;
    color: #fff;
    text-shadow: 0 0 2px rgba(0,0,0,.3);
    font-family: sans-serif;
    box-shadow:
        inset 0 0 2px 0 rgba(255,255,255,.4),
        inset 0 0 3px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.4),
        inset 0 0 3px 5px rgba(0,0,0,.05),
        2px 2px 4px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.25);
    border-radius: 4px;
    padding: 8px 16px;;
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: 14px;
    position: relative;
}
.button.red { background: #EA3D33; }
.button.green { background: #7ED321; }
.button.blue { background: #4A90E2; }
.button:before, .button:after {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    left: 2px;
    right: 2px;
    height: 3px;
}
.button:before {
    top: 0;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 4px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 4px;
    background: rgba(255,255,255,.6);
    box-shadow: 0 1px 2px 0 rgba(255,255,255,.6);
}
.button:after {
    bottom: 0;
    border-top-left-radius: 4px;
    border-top-right-radius: 4px;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,.15);
    box-shadow: 0 -1px 2px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.15);
}
```

and a fiddle to demonstrate: http://jsfiddle.net/pn4qk3wL/

Comment: Thank you! Works in Chrome, Firefox, Opera, Safari and IE 9-11.